# Appending to the list value of dictionary in python

Tags: python

What is going on here when I try to append to the value of dictionary which appears to be the list? It appears that I can't.

```
>>>b={}

>>>b["input"]=[3,4,5]

>>>b
{'input': [3, 4, 5]}

>>>b["input"]=b["input"].append(3)

>>>b
{'input': None}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Thanks to all the answers! So silly of me.

Comment: Since all the answers suggest the same thing, I am accepting the answer of the one who has lowest SO reputation. Hope you guys don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `b["input"].append(3)`, it **modifies** the dictionary, **BUT**! it doesn't return **anything**!

So you'd better do `b["input"].append(3)`

Answer (score 3):

`append` is an in-place method and always returns `None`.  Your code should be:

```
b["input"]=b["input"] + [3]
```

or even better:

```
b["input"].append(3)
```

Comment: Note that these are somewhat different. The first version constructs a new list, while the second alters the existing list. This matters if there are any other names for the b['input'] list. EG `foo = [1, 2]; b["input"] = foo`

Answer (score 2):

You're reassigning `b["input"]` to the return value of `append`, which changes the list in place and does not return anything.

Just change it in place:

```
b["input"].append(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

`b["input"].append(3)` returns `None`, which you assign back to `b["input"]`. Hence the value for that key becomes `None`.

Just remove the assignment part.

```
>>> b["input"].append(3)
```